# pagination serial number in next page

Tags: php, mysql

Hi iam using simple pagination code .It getting the problem is that the serial number start from 1 in every page in my pagination ,but  i need it from 11-20 in 2nd page, from 21-30 in 3rd page and so on.

my code is

```
$num_rec_per_page=10;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
 $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page+1; 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page"; 
 $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql); //run the query
 ?> 
<table>
<tr><td>SNo</td><td>Name</td><td>Phone</td></tr>
 <?php 
 $i=1;
 $start=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
 ?> 
        <tr><td><?php echo $i+$start; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></td>            
        </tr>
      <?php
       $i++; 
        }; 
       ?> 
     </table>
       <?php 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM users"; 
      $rs_result = mysql_query($sql); //run the query
    $total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
        echo "<a href='sample.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
    };
```

Please anyone help me.

Comment: this happen because $i start with 1, you need to set id based on page number, says 1+(10 * page)

Comment: Add the $i= $start_from; it  will works for you

Comment: use $start_from variable to display starting value

Comment: thanks for your help .Its working

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
   $i=$start_from;
     $start=0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

     echo "<tr><td>" .++$i. "</td>" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my code :

```
$num_rec_per_page=10;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
 $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page+1; 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page"; 
 $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql); //run the query
 ?> 
<table>
<tr><td>SNo</td><td>Name</td><td>Phone</td></tr>
 <?php 
 $i= $start_from;
 $start=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
 ?> 
        <tr><td><?php echo $i+$start; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></td>            
        </tr>
      <?php
       $i++; 
        }; 
       ?> 
     </table>
       <?php 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM users"; 
      $rs_result = mysql_query($sql); //run the query
    $total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
        echo "<a href='sample.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = ($num_rec_per_page * ($page-1))+1;
```

You have to try this for your `$start` so you get 11-20 on the 2nd page, 21-30 on the 3rd page.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. you can also syntax highlight code by selecting a block of code and pressing the code tool button in the editor, the one that looks like two curly braces { }  .