# Forloop counter with dynamic value range

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am using normal `html` table, and I am having more than **1000 records** to display. So,I used `pagination` concept and make **100 results per page**.

The problem is, for the serial number column, Iam using `forloop counter`, for first page I got serial numbers as 1 to 100, for second page also I am getting serial numbers as 1 to 100.

What I need is, it has to be 101 to 200 for second page and for third page it has to be 201 to 300, but it is showing 1 to 100.

How to make serial number like I am expecting?

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890993/pagination-serial-number-in-next-page)? You would need to supply your code I think.

Comment: @stuti, Iam trying in python, and i dont know php, so difficult to understand your post

Comment: Without your code which is creating problems, it is difficult for anyone to help you. We need to see what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can solve it like this:

1. Install mathfilters:
   **pip install django-mathfilters**
2. Add **'mathfilters'** to Installed_Apps
3. Replace **{{ forloop.counetr }}** by something like this in your template:

**{{ page_obj.number|add:-1|mul:page_obj.paginator.per_page|add:forloop.counter }}**

where:

page_obj.number - page number

page_obj.paginator.per_page - number of items on page